# ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am in the push code:

```
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Connection refused
```

error, I find on the Internet, see someone say is to create a config file in   `~/.ssh` directory, enter in the config file

```
Host github.com
User myusername
Hostname ssh.github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 443
```

but ping `github.com` appeared ssh again: connect to host `ssh.github.com` port 443: Connection refused error, ask Dachen to tell me the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

443 is the SSL port, not the SSH port, <s>so this configuration is definitely incorrect</s>. Remove this configuration file.

**UPDATE**: It turns out sshing to port 443 on github.com *is* actually valid, although most servers don't support this, and it may be blocked by your firewall even for github.com - see comment below.

It is unclear from your question whether the error message actually refers to port 22 or port 443, because the question contains two different error messages. If it refers to port 22, it is probably caused by a firewall between you and GitHub, like a firewall at your place of work or study. Use the HTTP URL for the repository instead of the SSH URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted ~/.ssh and regenerated. The problem was solved.

Comment: On Stackoverflow, when someone solves your problem, please click the tick to indicate that. This will indicate to other answerers that they don't need to look at the question, and it will show to any other people who have the same problem, that this is the solution.

Comment: It is possible to ssh over port 443. https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/